# HetrogenousImagesLayout/AsymmetricGridView using Flutter GridView

Tags: flutter, gridview, flutter-layout, staggeredgridlayout, staggeredgridlayoutmanager

[image: video list design]

How to make a design like this using Flutter GridView
Please help

Answer (score 0):

It seems what you want is similar to a staggered grid view: https://github.com/letsar/flutter_staggered_grid_view.

Using standard grids, you could have a SliverList with a SliverGrid, this post may help you: https://medium.com/flutter/slivers-demystified-6ff68ab0296f

Then, you can change crossAxisCount depending on the screen size.